# Sequalize: comparing parent column and child column in where clause inside include

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to do something similar ( I have removed unneccessory stuff)

```
Models.Parent.findAll({
        where: {
          parent_id: {
            [Models.Sequelize.Op.in]: [1, 2, 3, 4],
          },
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: Models.Child,
            as: 'child',
            where: {
               `$Parent.value$`: '$child.matchValue$'
            },
            required: true,
          },
        ],
      })
```

but the `where` inside `include` is not working? 
I want to compare Parent.value with Child.matchValue
Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use include like that, better make parentId a foreign key in child model and then use where to compare the required values.

Check this link: 
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html